# Make background position variable

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code...

```
document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
```

and it works fine but is there anyway to make the positioning variable with javascript?

like so...

```
document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundPosition = '0px VariableHere';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the background position is a string, you can just concatenate your value in.

For example:

```
var yValue = 20;
document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundPosition = '0px ' + yValue + 'px';
```

Comment: You should accept his answer if it helped you out. +1 for a good answer regardless.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer but they make you wait 9 minutes. Why are you telling people what to do? p.s. it did more than help... it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bgPos = '20px';
document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundPosition = '0px ' + bgPos;
```

Comment: Can you make that 20 variable

Comment: I would use Jonathan's answer if you want to reference 20 as an integer :)