# Javascript DOM background position getelementbyid()?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, background-position

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630840/make-background-position-variable) that I can position my div background image using:

```
var yValue = 20;
document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundPosition = '0px ' + yValue + 'px';
```

But how would I do this for the `body` `background-position` using JavaScript, does the body take an `id = 'bodyname'` for the `getElementById()` function parameter?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{ 
    background-image: url('image.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: 77px 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use $('body') to get the body

Comment: Is your solution JQuery? I did try using this `var bodyElements = document.getElementsByTagName('body');` from the answer below and it didn't work. I don't like JQeury btw?

Comment: Yes, my solution is Jquery. It's help you across browser :)

Comment: @Stiger Does the solution on this page not work with Internet Explorer? I haven't actually checked all browser but most of the things I do only work in everything else besides IE which is fine since very few of us use IE anymore anyways.

Comment: It's work on IE9 (my PC): $('body').click(function() {})

Comment: @Stiger I'm on XP so 9 doesnt work for me which is fine but thanks for testing it. I'll try that too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select your body with getElementById you need to add an id to it:

html:

```
<body id="bodyid"></body>
```

javascript:

```
var body = document.getElementById('bodyid');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give the body an id, there is no problem with that. But you could just as easily get the element by the tagname.

```
var bodyElements = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
```

As that method returns an array, the body tag would be the first element:

```
bodyElements[0]
```